# Помогите сократить и сделать более практичнее код

Tags: node.js

```
const http = require("http");
const urlModule = require("url");
const fs = require("fs");

function getPage(page, res) {
    fs.readFile(`./${page}.html`, "utf8", (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            fs.readFile(`./404.html`, "utf8", (err, errData) => {
                res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                res.write(errData);
                res.end();
            });
        }else{
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        }
    });
}

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    let query = urlModule.parse(req.url, true).query;
    if(query && query.page){
        getPage(query.page, res);
    }
}).listen(8080);

// http://localhost:8080/?page=home
// http://localhost:8080/?page=contact
// http://localhost:8080/?page=about
// http://localhost:8080/?page=cghjtyj
```

Comment: Тут не сокращать, а удлинять надо...

Comment: И как это сделать? Что можно удалить я не пойму уже